# What does "%age" mean?

Tags: database, machine-learning, dataset

I have a dataset. There are some explanation in it. But I can't understand.

Exports: Exports of goods and services. Given as %age of the Total GDP

what does it mean? what is the percentage of age?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%age simply means percentage. The symbol % or "percent" + "age" combines into percentage.

Comment: Ohh, really☺️ I didn't understand what age means.